# How to make webpage on iOS keep playing video when exiting fullscreen

Tags: html, ios, css, video, video-streaming

I'm currently using a video from nginx on a webpage, however, I have a bunch of videos on the one webpage, and I want people to be able to fullscreen into the videos and come back out to the multiple camera view, while it does that just fine, getting out of fullscreen seems to pause the video I was watching though while I want it to keep playing, is there any way to do this using the video tag in the html file or by any other means?

Here's all Relevant code:

css style listed in header:

```
.VidSizing {
float:left;
width:25%;
height:50%;
object-fit:fill;
}
```

html videos in body:

```
<div id="VideoSpace" style="width:100%;height:450px">
  <video id="player1" src="/hls1/stream1.m3u8" class="VidSizing" muted 
playsinline autoplay controls></video>
  <video id="player2" src="/hls2/stream2.m3u8" class="VidSizing" muted 
playsinline autoplay controls></video>
  <video id="player3" src="/hls3/stream3.m3u8" class="VidSizing" muted 
playsinline autoplay controls></video>
  <video id="player4" src="/hls4/stream4.m3u8" class="VidSizing" muted 
playsinline autoplay controls></video>
  <video id="player5" src="/hls5/stream5.m3u8" class="VidSizing" muted 
playsinline autoplay controls></video>
  <video id="player6" src="/hls6/stream6.m3u8" class="VidSizing" muted 
playsinline autoplay controls></video>
  <video id="player7" src="/hls7/stream7.m3u8" class="VidSizing" muted 
playsinline autoplay controls></video>
</div>
```

If more information is needed or you have any insight, feel free to ask. Also, no, I'm not specifying any css or anything elsewhere which is using the player ids or the div id, just the class (I'm doing this for a specific reason).

Edit 1: Full Screening one video does not seem to affect the playback of any others though in case this helps.

Comment: I have noticed this isn't the case when messing around in wordpress using other players, so I think it has something to do with the way iOS natively plays video.

Comment: This also occurs outside of wordpress in any webpage, so it's not a wordpress thing specifically either.